# Webpack is importing modules from my machine's global `node_modules`. How do I get it to only import from my project's `node_modules`?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm migrating a project from using Grunt to using Webpack. This project uses jQuery. I noticed that the bundled code was working fine, even though I hadn't yet added jQuery to `package.json`, which seemed strange.

Looking at the output of `webpack --mode=development --display-modules`, I saw:

```
[../../../../../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js] /Users/rothomas/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js 274 KiB {index} [built]
```

That is: it seems at some point I ran `npm install --global jquery`, and Webpack is importing that jQuery. I don't want this to happen, because my teammates/server won't have jQuery installed in `$HOME`.

The obvious solution is for me to just remove jQuery from my `$HOME/node_modules` (no idea how it got there anyway), which will cause Webpack to fail until I add it to `package.json`, as expected.

But I'd like to know:

1. **Why** does Webpack use `$HOME/node_modules`? I understand this is the default behavior of Node package resolvers, but it seems very error-prone since I imagine many other developers keep their projects nested under `$HOME`.
2. How can I specify the scope within which Webpack should be trying to resolve modules?

(I looked at Webpack's [documentation on resolvers](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules), but it's not very clear to me.)

Here is my current Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

function pathTo(filepath) {
    return path.join(__dirname, filepath);
}

module.exports = function (env, argv) {
    return {
        entry: {
            'index': [
                pathTo('src/scripts/index.js'),
                pathTo('src/scss/index.scss'),
            ]
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/env'
                        ]
                    },
                    test: /\.js$/,
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(scss|css|sass)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                url: false,
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                sassOptions: {
                                    outputStyle: 'expanded',
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            path: pathTo('web'),
        },
        plugins: [
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
        ],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your app is located inside the directory that has your global `node_modules` directory.

Webpack (and for that matter all node resolvers) will keep searching up your tree until it finds a directory that has a node-modules directory. then it will check in there for jquery. It continues doing this until it either finds what it's looking for, or if it reaches the root of your filesystem.

Comment: I understand that's the default behavior of Node resolvers, although am a little surprised Webpack follows the same behavior since it seems like it could cause so many errors -- especially since I imagine many developers keep projects nested under $HOME. Is there a way to prevent Webpack from doing this?

Comment: Your global node_modules should not be directly in $HOME. A better place would be $HOME/bin .

Comment: Ah, hard to argue with that. I'm using NVM so all my modules should be nested under that, but it looks like I accidentally did an `npm i` in `$HOME` at some point. Thanks! I'd still like to know, though, how to constrain Webpack's scope to a certain directory and its subdirectories?

Comment: If you want my opinion, don't keep any development projects in your home directory. I keep employer projects in `/companyname`, and personal projects in `/repos`.